# Purpose of Mybatis

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

I'm asked to use Mybatis on a project and I am really confused about why I should use and how can I use. I have read lots of resources about it but I cannot even manage to configure to my project. Is there any tutorials which explains from zero? Because all resources which I have read assumes that you are already using it (or I am so foreign to this topic, so I cannot even understand what is going on).

Thank you.

Comment: "What is MyBatis?
MyBatis is a first class persistence framework with support for custom SQL, stored procedures and advanced mappings. MyBatis eliminates almost all of the JDBC code and manual setting of parameters and retrieval of results. MyBatis can use simple XML or Annotations for configuration and map primitives, Map interfaces and Java POJOs (Plain Old Java Objects) to database records." None of that sounds like it assumes you're already using it. I think you should talk to whoever asked you to use it... this question is too broad as it stands.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, as you said I have never used them before but I am learning, I suppose. I just panic because they are too stranger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See using of any persistence framework depends upon what you want to achieve, ease of use and etc..
For example Hibernate works better if your view is more object-centric. If however you view is more database-centric then Mybatis is a much stronger choice.

What I meant to say is you have more control over sql in Mybatis and it is not heavy. While hiberante can be used in cases where you don't want more of sql work to be done and you want to play in terms of objects. Mybatis  also supports mapping to objects like map, list etc as well.

Although hiberante also provide support to write sql but its easiness is when we don't want to play SQL level rather we just say persist this object and hiberante creates sql for you.

In mybatis you have better control over sql's, you can even provide sql hints (if needed) externally or can change sql's without modifying relationship between Pojos as we need to do in Hibernate.

For refrences you can read:-

**MyBatis-3-User-Guide** or **mybatis-spring-1.0.1-reference** or **PacktPub.Java.Persistence.with.MyBatis.3**

Note:- You may get reference related to name ibatis as well Because MyBatis is iBATIS. 
iBatis was renamed to mybatis when it left apache.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have read MyBatis-3-User-Guide, actually it make me confused but I see that it is because of my lack of knowledge. Thank you for your interest.